# Laravel Artisan & Composer commands on deployment

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.7, laravel-envoy

What [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and [Artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan) commands are necessary to run during deployment of a brand new Laravel application? Per Laravel 5.7 [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/deployment), are these the only essential commands?

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: Depending on your app and how much you use cacheing, clearing views and caches could have a big impact on performance. I think those are best left out of your automatic process, and only run when needed.

Comment: @Jeff what do you mean only run when needed? If an app has its views or configs cached, when would they be refreshed? I think the only way is to include them in deployment (as fresh code could change the views and configs, so they need refreshing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods are:

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
composer dump-autoload
```

The others are optional.

1. Do you cache your configs? If yes, include `php artisan config:cache`
2. Do you cache your routes? If yes, include `php artisan route:cache`
3. Do you cache your views? If yes, include `php artisan view:cache`
4. Do you want to flush your app cache every time you deploy? If yes, include `php artisan cache:clear`

Beware that flushing your app cache could have many undesirable effects, especially if you're using your cache system for sessions, queues, etc. as it would clear out everything

Comment: Both of those commands generate optimized autoload files. These two run at the same time seem somewhat redundant.

Comment: Yours. composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
composer dump-autoload

Comment: No they are not the same command. You can refer composer's documentation. The first one optimizes autoload files and the second one clears them out.

Comment: If you run them back to back... > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: bensampo/laravel-enum
Discovered Package: binarytorch/larecipe
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Package manifest generated successfully.

Comment: I see. Just checked composer.json, Laravel triggers the second through a hook. Yes in that case you can skip the second one